# Raspberry pi freezes after 20 minutes of use

Tags: python, gui, tkinter

using tkinter i have made a GUI in which a video plays continuously in a loop until the ultrasonic sensor detects a person in front of it. when a person is detected it displays a messages"hi..welcome".
everything works fine but after running for around 20 minutes the raspberry pi freezes with blank black display.

```
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import time
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep
import serial
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen

movie1 = ("/home/pi/1.mp4")

last_state1 = True

quit_video = True

player = False

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

TRIG = 23
ECHO = 24

GPIO.setup(TRIG,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(ECHO,GPIO.IN)

window1 = tk.Tk()
window1.overrideredirect(1)
window1.geometry("900x1200")
window1.configure(background="black")

def create_main_window():

    def off():
        window.destroy()
        on()

    window = tk.Tk()
    window.overrideredirect(1)
    window.geometry("900x1200")
    window.configure(background="black")

    w1 = Label(window, text="Hi..WELCOME..", bg="black", fg="white", font="Times 110")
    w1.place(relx=.5, rely=.4, anchor="c")

    window.after(2000, off)
    window.mainloop()            



def on():
    player = False
    timeout = time.time() + 50
    while True:       
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
        print ("wating for sensor to settle")
        time.sleep(1)

        GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
        time.sleep(0.00001)
        GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==0:
                pulse_start = time.time()

        while GPIO.input(ECHO)==1:
                pulse_end = time.time()

        pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

        distance = pulse_duration * 17150
        distance = round(distance, 2)

        if distance > 1 and distance < 150:
            print ("Distance:",distance - 0.5, "cm")
            os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
            create_main_window()
        else:
            if not player:
                os.system('killall omxplayer.bin')
                omxc = Popen(['omxplayer', '-b', movie1])
                player = True                    
            else:
                print("hi")
        if time.time() > timeout:
            on()

window1.after(2000, on)
window1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Check out this question: [Ultrasonic Sensor + omxplayer block CPU](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103457/ultrasonic-sensor-omxplayer-block-cpu). The code there uses exactly the same infinite loops as you do, which get stuck forever if an edge of the ultrasonic sensor signal is ever missed.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying to quit omxplayer more cleanly (python3) :

```
import subprocess,time
myprocess = subprocess.Popen(['omxplayer','-b','/opt/vc/src/hello_pi/hello_video/test.h264'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep(5)
myprocess.stdin.write('q'.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: thank you @CoderMike .i will try quiting omxplayer with this. but is the freezing because of this mainly or something else??

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it would seem sensible to try and exit omxplayer cleanly rather than killing it - it might leave stuff in memory.

Comment: killing a process is not inherently unsafe. The problem with `killall` is that you don't know which process (and how many of them) you really kill. In rare cases, a process ID might be reused on a system with a heavy load, and then `killall` will kill a completely unrelated process.